# How to use Salesforce DX to search for keywords within metadata such as APEX class, triggers and etc?

Tags: salesforcedx, force.com-ide

I'm not a developer. However, I find that IDE tool like Force.com Eclipse is useful to help me with analysis. I mostly use Force.com Eclipse to search for certain key word, like Field_Name__c, and it will display where the field is being referenced or used even in classes/custom setting.

However, now Force.com Eclipse has been sunsetted. I am new to Salesforce DX and still trying to learn about the concept of using CLI. Can anyone here guide or share how could i use Salesforce DX Visual Studio to perform such searching?

Comment: just use `cntrlF` keyword in IDE. it search the entire your org metadata

Comment: `ctrl+shift+F'  it search the entire your Project metadata